# Rule a second line after parts in question environment

Tags: rules

I need to be able to put a second line for the answer to be written where the red line is in the picture below. But I can't get `\hrulefill` to work. It just does not draw the line! I want it to go from the current indent to just before the right margin.

This is my code for this section within the `\question` environment:

```
\part[2]
Calculate the mean.\hrulefill \\
\hrulefill
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Leave a gap (an empty line) between the two `\hrulefill`s:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\points}[1]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\makebox[2em][r]{(#1)}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  Calculate the mean. \hrulefill \points{2}

  \hrulefill

  \item
  Calculate the median. \hrulefill \points{2}

  \hrulefill

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `\hrule` instead of `\hrulefill`.